# Is the following scenario possible with Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I have been reading twilio documentation but didn't find anything related to this case

Say I made a call to a bank through twilio.device.connect, the bank asked me to press 1 to transfer call to an agent, then I have implemented a keypad where user can press 1 , but How will i pass that no through twilio API, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You will want to hook your keypad up to the the `sendDigits` method of the `Twilio.Connection` object that represents the call. Check out the documentation here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/connection#sendDigits